# Label in GA not set when firing event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

I need some help with a project I'm working on. I've build an HTML5 video with a playlist and I'm having issues setting up multiple labels in GA so I can track each individual video plays. I found the code online but having some problems changing it to my video player. I want to be able to set the label as the attribute data-description any help would be appreciated.  https://jsfiddle.net/2zkyh1f2/

The code is below:

```
    <section id="video-container">
        <video id="video-player" controls="controls" poster="" src="" data-description=""></video>

        <div id="description" label="" type="text"> </div>

        <ul id="playlist">
            <li id="videoweek" data-description movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 1 " type="video/mp4" moviesposter="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg">
                <img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail">

            </li>
            <li id="videoweek" data-description="video 1" movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 2 " type="video/mp4"> <img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail"></li>

             <li id="videoweek" data-description="video 2"n movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 3 " type="video/mp4"> <img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail"></li>

              <li id="videoweek" data-description="video 3" movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 4 " type="video/mp4"> <img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail"></li>

               <li id="videoweek" data-description="video 4" movieurl="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" label="This is video number 5 " type="video/mp4"> <img src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg" class="video-thumbnail"></li>


        </ul>



    </section>
$(function() {
$("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
    $("#video-player").attr({
        "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": "",
        "autoplay": "autoplay",
        "data-description": $(this).attr("data-description")
    })
})
 $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
    $("#description").attr({
        "label": $(this).attr("label")
    }).text($(this).attr("label"))
})
$("#video-player").attr({
    "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
    "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter"),
    "data-description": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("data-description")
    })
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false)
      var videoId = document.getElementById('video-player')
      //var videoTitle = $(this).attr('data-description')


      var videoTitle = $('#videoweek').click(function () {
                           console.log($(this).attr('data-description'));
                       });
      console.log(videoTitle);

      function init () {
        videoId.addEventListener('ended', videoEnd, false)
        videoId.addEventListener('timeupdate', videoTimeUpdate, false)
        videoId.addEventListener('play', videoPlay, false)
        videoId.addEventListener('pause', videoPause, false)
      }

      function setKeyFrames (duration) {
        var quarter = (duration / 4).toFixed(1)
        sessionStorage.setItem('one', quarter)
        sessionStorage.setItem('two', (quarter * 2).toFixed(1))
        sessionStorage.setItem('three', (quarter * 3).toFixed(1))
      }

      function videoTimeUpdate () {
          var curTime = videoId.currentTime.toFixed(1)
          switch (curTime) {
            case sessionStorage.getItem('one'):
              ga('send', 'event', 'video', '25% video played', videoTitle)
              sessionStorage.setItem('one', null)
            case sessionStorage.getItem('two'):
              ga('send', 'event', 'video', '50% video played', videoTitle)
              sessionStorage.setItem('two', null)
            case sessionStorage.getItem('three'):
              ga('send', 'event', 'video', '75% video played', videoTitle)
              sessionStorage.setItem('three', null)
          }
      }

      function videoEnd () {
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', '100% video played', videoTitle)
      }

      function videoPlay () {
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'video played', videoTitle)
        setKeyFrames(this.duration)
      }

      function videoPause () {
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'video paused', videoTitle)
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a minor problem of your `videoTitle`:

```
    function videoTimeUpdate() {
        var curTime = videoId.currentTime.toFixed(1);
        var videoTitle = $(this).attr('data-description');
        switch (curTime) {
            case sessionStorage.getItem('one'):
                ga('send', 'event', 'video', '25% video played', videoTitle)
                sessionStorage.setItem('one', null)
            case sessionStorage.getItem('two'):
                ga('send', 'event', 'video', '50% video played', videoTitle)
                sessionStorage.setItem('two', null)
            case sessionStorage.getItem('three'):
                ga('send', 'event', 'video', '75% video played', videoTitle)
                sessionStorage.setItem('three', null)
        }
    }

    function videoEnd() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', '100% video played', $(this).attr('data-description'))
    }

    function videoPlay() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'video played', $(this).attr('data-description'))
        setKeyFrames(this.duration)
    }

    function videoPause() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'video paused', $(this).attr('data-description'))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

This is working fine but it is always sending to GA the same data description unless I refresh the page. Is there any way I can send different data-description without refreshing the page?

Comment: @Joe, I tested above code. `data-description` varies based on the clicked `videoweek` without refreshing the page. Is your web page running that way?

Comment: Can you point out what the issue was? I have a similar issue with only getting "(not set)" but I don't have the same code base obviously..

Comment: The problem was `videoTitle` which the question author didn't get it right. And my fix was simply getting it by accessing the attribute `data-description` of the video element right inside the event handlers.